# Timeseries model using keras/tensorflow batch_outputs error in Python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Getting this error while trying run predict. Tried all sorts of solutions nothing seem to work.

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-0220993f4f06> in <module>
     12 # Forecasting n steps ahead
     13 n_ahead = 100
---> 14 yhat = deep_learner.predict_n_ahead(n_ahead)
     15 yhat = [y[0] for y in yhat]

<ipython-input-13-1540bc8bb71c> in predict_n_ahead(self, n_ahead)
    142         for _ in range(n_ahead):
    143             # Making the prediction
--> 144             fc = self.model.predict(X)
    145             yhat.append(fc)
    146 

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflowenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    128       raise ValueError('{} is not supported in multi-worker mode.'.format(
    129           method.__name__))
--> 130     return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    131 
    132   return tf_decorator.make_decorator(

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflowenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1612             callbacks.on_predict_batch_end(end_step, {'outputs': batch_outputs})
   1613       callbacks.on_predict_end()
-> 1614     all_outputs = nest.map_structure_up_to(batch_outputs, concat, outputs)
   1615     return tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(all_outputs)
   1616 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_outputs' referenced before assignment
```

```
Class/functions the code: 
    class DeepModelTS():
    """
    A class to create a deep time series model
    """
    def __init__(
        self, 
        data: pd.DataFrame, 
        Y_var: str,
        lag: int,
        LSTM_layer_depth: int, 
        epochs=10, 
        batch_size=4,
        train_test_split=0
    ):

        self.data = data 
        self.Y_var = Y_var 
        self.lag = lag 
        self.LSTM_layer_depth = LSTM_layer_depth
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.train_test_split = train_test_split

    @staticmethod
    def create_X_Y(ts: list, lag: int) -> tuple:
        """
        A method to create X and Y matrix from a time series list for the training of 
        deep learning models 
        """
        X, Y = [], []

        if len(ts) - lag <= 0:
            X.append(ts)
        else:
            for i in range(len(ts) - lag):
                Y.append(ts[i + lag])
                X.append(ts[i:(i + lag)])

        X, Y = np.array(X), np.array(Y)

        # Reshaping the X array to an LSTM input shape 
        X = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1))

        return X, Y         

    def create_data_for_NN(
        self,
        use_last_n=None
        ):
        """
        A method to create data for the neural network model
        """
        # Extracting the main variable we want to model/forecast
        y = self.data[self.Y_var].tolist()

        # Subseting the time series if needed
        if use_last_n is not None:
            y = y[-use_last_n:]

        # The X matrix will hold the lags of Y 
        X, Y = self.create_X_Y(y, self.lag)

        # Creating training and test sets 
        X_train = X
        X_test = []

        Y_train = Y
        Y_test = []

        if self.train_test_split > 0:
            index = round(len(X) * self.train_test_split)
            X_train = X[:(len(X) - index)]
            X_test = X[-index:]     
            
            Y_train = Y[:(len(X) - index)]
            Y_test = Y[-index:]

        return X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test

    def LSTModel(self):
        """
        A method to fit the LSTM model 
        """
        # Getting the data 
        X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = self.create_data_for_NN()

        # Defining the model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(self.LSTM_layer_depth, activation='relu', input_shape=(self.lag, 1)))
        model.add(Dense(1))
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

        # Defining the model parameter dict 
        keras_dict = {
            'x': X_train,
            'y': Y_train,
            'batch_size': self.batch_size,
            'epochs': self.epochs,
            'shuffle': False
        }

        if self.train_test_split > 0:
            keras_dict.update({
                'validation_data': (X_test, Y_test)
            })

        # Fitting the model 
        model.fit(
            **keras_dict
        )

        # Saving the model to the class 
        self.model = model

        return model

    def predict(self) -> list:
        """
        A method to predict using the test data used in creating the class
        """
        yhat = []

        if(self.train_test_split > 0):
        
            # Getting the last n time series 
            _, X_test, _, _ = self.create_data_for_NN()        

            # Making the prediction list 
            yhat = [y[0] for y in self.model.predict(X_test)]

        return yhat

    def predict_n_ahead(self, n_ahead: int):
        """
        A method to predict n time steps ahead
        """    
        X, _, _, _ = self.create_data_for_NN(use_last_n=self.lag)        

        # Making the prediction list 
        yhat = []

        for _ in range(n_ahead):
            # Making the prediction
            fc = self.model.predict(X)
            yhat.append(fc)

            # Creating a new input matrix for forecasting
            X = np.append(X, fc)

            # Ommiting the first variable
            X = np.delete(X, 0)

            # Reshaping for the next iteration
            X = np.reshape(X, (1, len(X), 1))

        return yhat
```

Input is a dataframe of type:

- index:                                        `int64`
- Date:                                         `datetime64[ns]`
- Region:                                      `object`
- Thermal Generation Actual (in MU):            `float64`
- `dtype: object`

`Dataframe` is of timeseries form.
The forecast on the training set is working fine but further facing error.

Comment: input : aheaddeep_learner = DeepModelTS(
data=Data_0,
Y_var='Thermal Generation Actual (in MU)',
lag=4,
LSTM_layer_depth=100,
epochs=32,
train_test_split=0
)
# Fitting the model
deep_learner.LSTModel()
# Forecasting n steps ahead
n_ahead = 100
yhat = deep_learner.predict_n_ahead(n_ahead)
yhat = [y[0] for y in yhat]